# How do I upload an image with Django with an ImageField?

Tags: python, django, file, upload, imagefield

guys.
I have a problem where I want to change the thumbnail on my website of a Model (talking about 3D printing here but also Django ones) but Django does not change it.

models.py

```
class Model3D(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='models/thumbnails', null=True)
```

I tried two different forms.py
Version 1

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
    """Image upload form."""
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

Version 2 (ignore the following name, it was just a fast test)

```
class ModelCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model3D
        fields = ['name', 'thumbnail']
        help_texts = {
            'thumbnail': ("Gebe hier den Namen des Modelles ein.")
        }
```

views.py

```
def save_settings(request, pk):
    model = get_object_or_404(Model3D, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print("request.method == 'POST'" + str(dir(saveModel)))
        model.name = request.POST.get('name', model.name)
        model.description = request.POST.get('description', model.description)
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            model.thumbnail = form.cleaned_data['image']
            model.save()
            return HttpResponse('image upload success')
        model.save()
        return redirect('settings_model', pk=model.pk)

    return redirect('settings_model', pk=model.pk)
```

I do have enctype="multipart/form-data in my template. Please help!

Comment: It should work with the `ModelForm`, however you need to assign the instance: `form = ModelCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = model)`. Then `form.save()` will do the trick. The various options are described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)

Comment: Note also that having `description` and `name` in your `ModelForm` will be better, since it lets you validate and clean the data (you should **never** directly assign data from `request.POST` to your model since that's insecure).